# FullCalendar giving error: Uncaught TypeError: $(...).fullCalendar is not a function

Tags: c#, asp.net, fullcalendar

I am trying to incorporate fullcalendar into my asp.net website but i keep getting this error.

```
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).fullCalendar is not a function
```

I've looked through the other threads on this error and tried using the downloaded zip file of full calendar and even replaced the script lines with website allocated references.

its giving me the error where i call `$('#calendar').fullCalendar({` in the below code

This is my code :

```
    <link href='../fullcalendar/fullcalendar.css' rel='stylesheet' />
<link href='../fullcalendar/fullcalendar.print.css' rel='stylesheet' media='print' />
<script src='http://fullcalendar.io/js/fullcalendar-2.1.1/lib/moment.min.js'></script>
<script src='http://fullcalendar.io/js/fullcalendar-2.1.1/lib/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script src="http://fullcalendar.io/js/fullcalendar-2.1.1/lib/jquery-ui.custom.min.js"></script>
<script src='http://fullcalendar.io/js/fullcalendar-2.1.1/fullcalendar.min.js'></script>

<script>

    $(document).ready(function () {

        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            defaultDate: '2015-02-12',
            editable: true,
            eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
            events: [
            {
                title: 'All Day Event',
                start: '2015-02-01'
            }
```

and where i call it :

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <div id='calendar'></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Are you getting any errors in the console?

Comment: nope, this is if i inspect element in google chrome. it runs fine but just shows my master page without any content

Comment: Check your references.

Comment: yes thats what i thought too but its a downloaded pack from adam shaw. i used his files that i downloaded from his site. and then that didnt work so i went to stackoverflow and saw other people posted about the same error and one guy said to use the http references instead. so did that too in the code above but still nothing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to add the class in the container

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row full-calendar">

        <div class="col-sm-9">
            <div id="calendar"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

or look at devOOps theme, the example is very simple

http://devoops.me/themes/devoops/